# Adding text to a div in Android WebView dynamically using Javascript

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am planning to fill up the text on this website using Javascript

http://customercare.indianrailways.gov.in/criscm/common/complaint_registration.seam

And here is the code for my WebView below

The problem is couple of input fields are dynamic in the WebPage and 
I try to use .innerHTML and load some text/html into div but it's not loading.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.details1);

                    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
                    String s2="http://customercare.indianrailways.gov.in/criscm/common/complaint_registration.seam";
                    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                    mWebView.getSettings().setStandardFontFamily("Arial");
                    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(17);
                    if(mWebView.getSettings().getBuiltInZoomControls())
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    mWebView.loadUrl(s2);

                    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


                    });

                   WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
                   {
                       // Override page so it's load on my view only
                       @Override
                       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            String Staffname = "cristian";
                            String mode="InTrain";
                            String date="27/09/2014 07:14";
                            String contactno="941432344";
                            String emailid="rdasdamn@gmail.com";
                            String address1="28 asdasdasdasd";
                            String address2="Siwerwerweradi";
                            String address3="Madurai";
                            String address4="werwer India";
                            String remarks="Shan asdasdasdas dasdasdas";
                            /*String html="<div><label for='complaintRegister:causeOfSubComplaint:subCatComplaint' class='name outputText'><label>Sub Complaint :</label><span id='complaintRegister:causeOfSub"
                                    +"Complaint:j_id60' class='required'>*</span></label><span class='value outputText'><table id='complaintRegister:causeOfSubComplaint:subCatComplaint' class='radio'>"
                                    +"<tbody><tr><td><input type='radio' name='complaintRegister:causeOfSubComplaint:subCatComplaint' id='complaintRegister:causeOfSubComplaint:subCatComplaint:0'"
                                    +"value='152' autocomplete='off'><label for='complaintRegister:causeOfSubComplaint:subCatComplaint:0'> Non availability of Manning Staff</label></td>"
                                    +"</tr><tr><td><input type='radio' name='complaintRegister:causeOfSubComplaint:subCatComplaint' id='complaintRegister:causeOfSubComplaint:subCatComplaint:1'"
                                    +"value='153' autocomplete='off'><label for='complaintRegister:causeOfSubComplaint:subCatComplaint:1'> Gates not open during late night hours at the halting"
                                    +"stations</label></td></tr></tbody></table></span><span class='error'></span></div>";*/

                            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:"
                            + "document.getElementById('complaintRegister:nameOfStaff:nameOfStaff').value = '"+Staffname+"';"
                            + "document.getElementById('complaintRegister:complaintMode').value = '"+mode+"';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:decIncidentDate:incidentDateInputDate').value='"+date+"';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:contactNumber:contactNo').value='"+contactno+"';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:emailId:emailId').value='"+emailid+"';"   
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:address1Id').value='"+address1+"';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:address2Id').value='"+address2+"';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:address3Id').value='"+address3+"';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:address4Id').value='"+address4+"';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:complaintModePanel:platformNumber').visible='True';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:complaintModePanel:stationName').visible='True';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:remarks').value='"+remarks+"';"
                            +"document.getElementById('complaintRegister:causeOfComplaint').innerHTML='"+"<a href='###'>Shan</a>dsadas"+"';");
                            super.onPageFinished(view, url);


                        }


                   };
                   mWebView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
                 // mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new HelloWebViewClient());      
        }


}
```

Comment: did you try to load the page in desktop browser and tried to run same javascript in address bar? was it working?

Comment: How to do it for a desktop browser??